# Git with Large Static Files

Tags: git, large-files, git-lfs

I have data sets that I would like to keep with analysis code. Sometimes the data is binary and sometimes its text i.e. csv files. The data sets can get large (more detail below) so my first inclination is to use git LFS to store the data sets with the code repositories. However, the files don't ever change.

I'd like to keep the data sets in git for 2 reasons.

1. In the past I have accidentally deleted or modified data that is time consuming or impossible to recollect.
2. I'd like to be able to get the code and the data at the same time to simplify the process of returning to a project.

Most of my data sets have files that are generally between 10MB to 1GB and the total size 
 of the data set ranges from 1GB-100GB. My largest data sets contain files as large as 100GB and have a total size in excess of 2TB. Though, I'm guessing that git may not work at all for these extremely large sets.

I'm wondering

- Does it make sense to use git lfs for my data sets if they aren't changing? It seems like the largest benefit of git lfs (not having to carry around the history of different versions of a big binary in the repo) is moot in my case since there's only ever 1 version of a given file.
- I can see occasionally wanting to delete a data set, would lfs work better for this use case?
- Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: See if [this](https://dvc.org/) looks like a good option (instead of keeping data directly in Git). I've never used it, so can't add much more than a link.